# Reading binary file in Python and writing it into another patching by nonzero bytes from the third file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, binary, patch

In Python-3.x which is the best way to patch binary file with nonzero bytes from another (creating third output file), all of course keeping original byte sequence?

Just to read out source file and patch file and write source byte-by-byte
is not a problem, but how to parse both of them byte-by-byte:

```
    output = open('File3', 'wb')
    patch = open('File2', "rb").read()
    with open('File1', 'rb') as f:
        bytei = f.read(1)
        while bytei != b"":
            output.write(bytei)
            bytei = f.read(1)
```

All files are small <50kb, speed isn't issue.

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear. Traditionally "patching" a file means finding certain spots in it and overwriting those parts, possibly also appending additional data to the end. However, I can also interpret your question to mean that you want to find zero bytes in File1 and fill them with bytes from File2.

Comment: Just replace with nonzeroes from patch file corresponding (by address from file beginning) bytes in source file (despite patch file length - it could be shorter) all other data - just copy from source to dest. file. Yes, i think it's some kind of patching, the thing is - those spots are contained in patch file.

Comment: Still not clear. You should attempt to write the code and then followup with specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then the following is what you are attempting to do:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('File1', 'rb') as f1, \
    open('File2', 'rb') as f2, \
    open('File3', 'wb') as f3:

    output = bytearray()

    for v1, v2 in zip_longest(f1.read(), f2.read()):
        output.append(v2 if v2 else v1)

    f3.write(output)
```

For example:

```
File1 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 00
File2 00 11 00 00 14 00 16
```

Gives:

```
File3 01 11 03 04 14 06 16 08 09 0a 00
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin! My approach was crude - i created nonzero bytes list from patch file and then counted bytes in source file - if counter matched byte number in the list - then it was written from patch, otherwise - from source. But somehow that didn't work for me.